# How to darken and add text to images on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ive tried multiple methods, but nothing seems to be working.

Ive recently stumbled upon this http://codepen.io/VectorQuanity/pen/qEeJoK, but when i try to implement it into my code, the text doesn't pop up on hover.

---

#### My code :

```js
$(".pic").hover(function() {
    $(".info", this).css("display", "block");
}, function() {
    $(".info", this).css("display", "none");
});

$('.hover').mouseover(function() {
    $('.text').css("visibility","visible");
});

$('.hover').mouseout(function() {
    $('.text').css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

```css
body {
    width: 1500px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:300);

ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
}

.logo {
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.pic {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.pic:hover > .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:99.5%;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
}

.info {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

footer{
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Gullible</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href=""></a>Home</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>Shop</li>
    <li class="logo"><a href=""></a>Gullible</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>Visit</li>
    <li><a href="text">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjj0l.jpg" class="hover">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjj0l.jpg">
    <p class="text">Wonder Women</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgwPb.jpg" class="hover">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgwPb.jpg">
    <p class="text">Batman</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8VTt.jpg" class="hover">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8VTt.jpg">
    <p class="text">Joker</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTZPO.jpg" class="hover">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTZPO.jpg">
    <p class="text">Bane</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aHn3.jpg" class="hover">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aHn3.jpg">
    <p class="text">Bane</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOzEN.jpg" class="hover">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOzEN.jpg">
    <p class="text">Bane</p>
  </div>
</div>


  <footer>
  <h2>Gullible</h2>
    <nav>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Shop</li>
      <li>Visit</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you always put gullible in the footer?

Comment: I just thought of a random word as the logo, and most websites have their logo in the header as well as the footer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few things in your code that could be improved. For example, you don't even need ANY JavaScript at all to achieve what you're looking for.

Check out the improved code below (which fixes your issue)!

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:300);

body {
    width: 1500px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header ul {
   display: flex;
   list-style-type: none;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
}

.logo {
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.pic {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.info {
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
    left : 0;
    top : 45%;
    right : 0;
    text-align : center;
    position: absolute;
}

.pic:hover > .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:99.5%;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    display: block;
}

.pic:hover .info {
    display: block;
}

footer{
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""></a>Home</li>
      <li><a href=""></a>Shop</li>
      <li class="logo"><a href=""></a>Gullible</li>
      <li><a href=""></a>Visit</li>
      <li><a href="text">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjj0l.jpg">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <p class="text">Wonder Women</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgwPb.jpg">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <p class="text">Batman</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8VTt.jpg">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <p class="text">Joker</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTZPO.jpg">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <p class="text">Bane</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aHn3.jpg">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <p class="text">Bane</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOzEN.jpg">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <p class="text">Bane</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <h2>Gullible</h2>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Shop</li>
      <li>Visit</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @LCAD : You're welcome. I just hope you actually learnt something from the changes I made ;-)